# WSO2 BAM issue with hive query to jdbc to MySQL external DB: error

Tags: wso2, hive

I am testing out pushing data into BAM from Perl via REST API's, which seems to be working well. Now working on the next step, which is to test the aggregation out to a separate MySQL DB on a different host, and I am getting an error that I can't seem to get past. See the stack trace below ..

```
Hive history file=/Users/<user>/local/wso2bam-2.4.1/tmp/hive/wso2-querylogs/hive_job_log_jskogsta_201406141932_1331503753.txt
Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler
[2014-06-14 19:33:00,180] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getStorageHandler(Table.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.execute(HiveServer.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:187)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.executeHiveQuery(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:577)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:287)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getStorageHandler(HiveUtils.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getStorageHandler(Table.java:273)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspClassLoader.findClass(JspClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspClassLoader.loadClass(JspClassLoader.java:108)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getStorageHandler(HiveUtils.java:144)
    ... 18 more

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
[2014-06-14 19:33:00,180] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
[2014-06-14 19:33:00,183] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.executeHiveQuery(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:577)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:287)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[2014-06-14 19:33:00,200] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ui.client.HiveExecutionClient} -  Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.stub.HiveExecutionServiceHiveExecutionException: HiveExecutionServiceHiveExecutionException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.stub.HiveExecutionServiceStub.executeHiveScript(HiveExecutionServiceStub.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.ui.client.HiveExecutionClient.executeScript(HiveExecutionClient.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.hive_002dexplorer.queryresults_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.hive_002dexplorer.queryresults_jsp:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I even downloaded the MySQL jar file and put into /lib:

```
[19:31:00] [<user>@enterprise ../local/wso2bam-2.4.1/lib]$ ls
ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar           org.wso2.carbon.logging-4.2.0.jar   tomcat
commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar       org.wso2.carbon.server-4.2.0.jar    transactions.properties
endorsed                org.wso2.ciphertool-1.0.0-wso2v2.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.tar     runtimes
[19:45:34] [<user>@enterprise ../local/wso2bam-2.4.1/lib]$
```

Here is the query that I am trying to execute within BAM admin gui, which is failing:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Summarized_Table ( payload_symbol STRING, payload_min INT, payload_price STRING, payload_volume INT, payload_max INT)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.JDBCStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'mapred.jdbc.driver.class' = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' ,
'mapred.jdbc.url' = 'jdbc:mysql://<IP>:<PORT>/testdb' ,
'mapred.jdbc.username' = '<USER>' ,
'mapred.jdbc.password' = '<PASS>' ,
'hive.jdbc.update.on.duplicate' = 'true' ,
'hive.jdbc.table.create.query' = 'CREATE TABLE testtable
                                (payload_symbol VARCHAR(10), payload_min INT, payload_price VARCHAR(20), payload_volume INT, payload_max INT) ');
```

The following query, which I am doing before this one works fine:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (Row_ID STRING, payload_symbol STRING,
          payload_min INT, payload_price STRING, payload_volume INT, payload_max INT)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "cassandra.host" = "127.0.0.1" ,
"cassandra.port" = "9160" ,
"cassandra.ks.name" = "EVENT_KS" ,
"cassandra.ks.username" = "<USER>" ,
"cassandra.ks.password" = "<PASS>" ,
"cassandra.cf.name" = "stockquote_stream" ,
"cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":key,payload_symbol,payload_min,payload_price,payload_volume,payload_max" );
```

I have confirmed that I am able to connect to the remote DB from this computer as well:

```
[19:51:22] [<USER>@enterprise ../local/wso2bam-2.4.1/lib]$ mysql -u currentcost -h <IP> --port=<PORT> -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 43
Server version: 5.5.34 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> exit
Bye
[19:51:46] [<USER>@enterprise ../local/wso2bam-2.4.1/lib]$
```

This is a standard default installation of BAM, with nothing done to it at all.

Anyone can point to a solution to the problem? Would be greatly appreciated!

[SOLUTION UPDATE] I managed to solve this, and believe it or not... $CARBON_CLASSPATH issue with 3rd party .jar for MySQL. Ended up putting the mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar file in the various /lib/ folders within the WSO2 BAM installation and it worked. Here is now the console log for the execution, and the data now shows up in the remote MySQL db.

```
Hive history file=/Users/<USER>/local/wso2bam-2.4.1/tmp/hive/wso2-querylogs/hive_job_log_<USER>_201406151106_798138044.txt
OK
OK
OK
Copying data from file:/Users/<USER>/projects/ccost/prod.txt
Copying file: file:/Users/<USER>/projects/ccost/prod.txt
Loading data to table default.producttable
OK
OK
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Execution log at: /Users/<USER>/local/wso2bam-2.4.1/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log
2014-06-15 11:13:07.935 java[2137:1003] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
[2014-06-15 11:13:08,473]  WARN {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient} -  Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
Hadoop job information for null: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2014-06-15 11:13:11,720 null map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-06-15 11:13:14,722 null map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
2014-06-15 11:13:17,725 null map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_local_0001
Execution completed successfully
Mapred Local Task Succeeded . Convert the Join into MapJoin
OK
```

Thus - so far so good. Now on to the next problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy any 3rd party library into `<BAM_HOME>/repository/components/lib` folder.

Comment: Got it eventually. Thanks! ;-)